# Jquery select all options that start with 'Urgent-'

Tags: jquery

Based on the below markup, how (in JQuery) would i select the options that start with `Urgent-` or `Urgent -` ?

```
<select name="List1" id="list1">
<option>One</option>
<option>Two</option>
<option>urgent-Three</option>
<option>Urgent-Four</option>
<option>Urgent - Five</option>
</select>
```

Based on the answer below I am using the following JQuery to wrap the matched elements in an `<optgroup>`.

```
$opts = $("#list1 > option").filter(function() {
    return /^Urgent\s?-/.test(this.innerHTML);
});

$opts.wrapAll('<optgroup label="Urgent">');
```

I need to remove the matched text from the option text resulting in markup like this:-

```
    <select name="List1" id="list1">
    <option>One</option>
    <option>Two</option>
    <optgroup label="Urgent">
    <option>Three</option>
    <option>Four</option>
    <option>Five</option>
    </optgroup>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method and [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
$("#list1 > option").filter(function() {
    return /^Urgent\s?-/.test(this.innerHTML);
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/th83R/

---

**UPDATE.** To follow your updated question, you have to modify the code a bit.

```
$("#list1 > option").filter(function() {
    var newVal = this.innerHTML.replace(/^urgent\s?-\s?/i, "");
    if (newVal != this.innerHTML) {
        this.innerHTML = newVal;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).wrapAll('<optgroup label="Urgent" />');​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/th83R/3/

Comment: How would I modify this to ignore case i.e. match `urgent-` and also I am using to code to do a `wrapall` in a tag afterwards, how would i remove the matched text from the tag. Will edit the question.

Comment: You can use `i` flag in the regular expression: `/^urgent\s?-/i`.